# Approximation of an Integral for T >> T_D

Tags: integration, analysis, approximation

In a lecture, we had the following integral:

$$C_{\text{V, mol}} = 9R\left(\frac{T}{T_D} \right)^3 \int_{0}^{x_D}\frac{x^4e^x}{\left( e^x-1\right)^2}dx,$$ where $x_D \equiv \frac{\hbar\omega_D}{k_BT}$, and $x = \frac{\hbar\omega}{k_BT}$ is the temperature. Now, we said that for $T\gg  T_D \equiv \frac{\hbar\omega_D}{k_B}$, we could approximate $C_{\text{V, mol}}$ as follows: 
$$C_{\text{V, mol}} \approx 9R \left( \frac{T}{T_D} \right)^3 \int_{0}^{T_D/T}x^2dx.$$
However, I don't know how to arrive at the last approximation. Clarification would be appreciated. :-)

Comment: I do not understang the upper bound in the last integral : it should stay $x_D$

Comment: This is Debye model : in the first integral, the upper bound is $\frac {T_D} T$. Have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model

Comment: $x_D = T_D / T$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it more or less $$I=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{x^4e^x}{\left( e^x-1\right)^2}dx$$

Expand the integrand around $x=0$
$$\frac{x^4e^x}{\left( e^x-1\right)^2}=x^2-\frac{x^4}{12}+\frac{x^6}{240}-\frac{x^8}{6048}+\frac{x^{10}}{172800}+O\left(x^
   {12}\right)$$

**Edit**

In terms of approximation of the integrand, much better is $\frac{12 x^2}{x^2+12}$.

The integral can be computed rigorously
$$I=12 t^2 \text{Li}_2\left(e^t\right)-24 t \text{Li}_3\left(e^t\right)+24
   \text{Li}_4\left(e^t\right)-\frac{e^t t^4}{e^t-1}+4 t^3 \log
   \left(1-e^t\right)-\frac{4 \pi ^4}{15}$$

Comment: Hi, how exactly did you expand the integrand? Let $I(x)$ be the integrand. Then according to the Taylor approximation, the first term is $I(0)$, which is in this case "$0/0$". Did you apply L'Hospital? Because if I do apply L'Hospital, I get $I(0) = 0$.

Comment: @MathIsFun. Composition of Taylor series for small $x$

Comment: I am sorry, I haven't heard of "composition of Taylor series" before.

Comment: @MathIsFun. Suppose that you want $\log(1+\sin(x))$ around $x=0$. You have two ways to do it for the same result. Think about it and come back.

Comment: I think I would first expand $1 + sin(x)$ around $x = 0$, which yields $1 + x$. Then I would expand $\log(1+x)$, which yields $\frac{1}{2}$. I cannot think of a second way, though.

Comment: @MathIsFun. I am speaking about more than one term. You could also do $\log(1+\sin(x))=\sin(x)-\frac 12 \sin^2(x)+ ...$ and later expand $\sin(x)$. You discovered my big love for that (starting 62+ years ago).

Comment: I definitely see why you love this! ;-) So we Taylor expand the outer functions and the inner functions, which is kind of "the chain rule for Taylor series". However, I am wondering that for the case $$I(x) = \frac{x^4e^x}{\left( e^x-1\right)^2}, $$ what would be the outer function? It wouldn't be $1/\left( e^x-1\right)^2$, would it? PS: Would you mind moving this discussion to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108080/discussion-between-claude-leibovici-and-mathisfun).